# Should hyperlinks be more notorious?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

I never thought of making a topic about it, but more than once I had to eyestrain (and placing my cursor over the whole text) to find the link within a paragraph. As the pic shrinks, it's easier to notice the hyperlinked text, but if you open it in its actual size I believe you can notice what I mean.

[image]

At least in Arqade, in order to make a difference between a link and normal text is to use the bold tag.

...or maybe it's just me and/or my two monitors! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What if hyperlinks looked like [this](http://i.imgur.com/MfG5rz7.png)?

Comment: [status-completed] on duplicate following the addition of underlines.